# Preparing grid for bigger words

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my drag and drop word game there is a set grid size of 6x6 (36 cells). It is populated by 6 3 letter words and 18 blank spaces.

At the moment as the grid is 2 words per row, when I add a word in the list that is longer that 3 letters it overlaps the grid when there is another word on that row.

I need some script that can give words bigger than 3 letters their own line so that the grid doesn't get overlapped.

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Here is the script that creates the table from the array list in the HTML...

```
var listOfWords = [];
var rndWord = [];
var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");

var i;
for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i) {

    listOfWords.push({
        "name": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
    });

    console.log(listOfWords);
    }

    console.log(listOfWords);

var chosenWords = [];
var cpy_list = listOfWords.slice();

for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cpy_list.length));
    console.log('push ' + cpy_list[rand].name);
    chosenWords.push(cpy_list[rand].name);
    cpy_list.splice(rand, 1);
    console.log(cpy_list);
        if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
        console.log('make a blank');
        chosenWords.push('   ');
    }
}

console.log(chosenWords);
var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

var guesses = {};
console.log(shuffledWords);
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    console.log(shuffledWords);
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        console.log(j);
        console.log(word);
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Here is the list of words in the HTML...

```
<ul style="display:none;" id="wordlist">

    <li data-word="mum" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/5/e/7/f/1195445022768793934Gerald_G_Lady_Face_Cartoon_1.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="cat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/9/9/5/119543969236915703Gerald_G_Cartoon_Cat_Face.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="dog" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/9/4/1/1195440435939167766Gerald_G_Dog_Face_Cartoon_-_World_Label_1.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="bug" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/4/b/4/2/1216180545881311858laurent_scarabe.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="rat" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/C/j/X/e/k/D/mouse-md.png"></li>

    <li data-word="dad" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/H/I/n/C/p/Z/bald-man-face-with-a-mustache-md.png"></li>

    <li data-word="cop" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/4/c/5/1194984609285255522police_man_ganson.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="pig" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/c/c/c/13286504431247546768Simple%20Pig%20Cartoon.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="sun" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/porkypig1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/b/1/2/11971486551534036964ivak_Decorative_Sun.svg.med.png"></li>

    <li data-word="kid" data-audio="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/daffyduck1.wav" data-pic="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/9/9/f/11954449391541537067Gerald_G_Girl_Face_Cartoon.svg.med.png"></li>
```

Comment: Can we use this as a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/Ldbdg/ Does it look OK to you? Note that I just copy/pasted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldbdg/1/ i have styled it here. Basically if you change one of the words in the list to a four letter word you will see what I mean @Jonas G. Drange

Comment: Have you had a look yet mate? @Jonas G. Drange

Comment: Yeah I took a look. I fear I need you to do some work before I can give you the easy fix. I am not expert enough to do it in the scripts current state.

Task: can you write it a bit less tight? It is now for loop after foor loop. Is there a way to make it a bit more prototype/object oriented?

Comment: I am not really that familiar with good object orientation. Do you mean putting them all in one function? @Jonas G. Drange

Comment: The concept means making the board an actual object with methods (functions) and properties. 
Consider if you had an object with a method called `board.populateRow([letters])`. The benefit is that it is easy to understand and work with. To be able to write this you need to read up on it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, lemme know if it helps...

```
var listOfWords = [];
var rndWord = [];
var counter = 0;
var ul = document.getElementById("wordlist");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; ++i) {

    listOfWords.push({
        "name": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-word"),
        "pic": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-pic"),
        "audio": ul.children[i].getAttribute("data-audio")
    });
}

var chosenWords = [];
var copylist = listOfWords.slice();

for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (copylist.length));
    chosenWords.push(copylist[rand].name);
    copylist.splice(rand, 1);
    if (chosenWords.length < 12) {
        chosenWords.push('   ');
    }

}

var shuffledWords = [];
shuffledWords = chosenWords.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
});

var guesses = {};
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length - 1; i += wordsPerRow) {

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
        var word = shuffledWords[j];
        guesses[word] = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');


            $(cell).addClass('drop-box').attr('data-word', word).attr('data-letter', word[k]);
            cell.textContent = word[k];

            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }

    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

$(".container").append(tbl);
```